# scrolltop not working with bootstrap grids

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to scroll into div using below code

```
 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#hot").offset().top}, 500);
```

this is working normally , but When I use it along with bootstrap grids , it is just scrolling little bit.

below is sample html and css I am testing

```
.mybox {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

..

```
      <div class="row">

        <h1 class="center" id="popular"> POPULAR DEALS </h1>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>

        <h1 id="hot" class='center'> HOT DEALS </h1>

        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
        <div class="mybox col-lg-4 col-xs-3">test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollhere">

    </div>
```

Here is demo - https://jsfiddle.net/4nymvo3a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work right because the Bootstrap grid uses floating. So, the offset for `#hot` is at the top of the grid, even though it appears below the first set of grid items. To fix the offset, you can add:

```
#hot
{
    clear: both;
}
```

to your CSS. This clears out the floating and correctly computes the offset of `#hot`, while not affecting the display. Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/t22sxxk6/.