# jQuery $(window).scrollTop(value) not working with a Jinja2 rendered Bootstrap 4 grid filled with images

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I am failing to get the jQuery `$(window).scrollTop(value)` code to work with a particular page in a Boostrapped Python-Flask-Jinja web application. 
The jQuery code works fine on two other pages of the web app.
I think it has something to do with the rendering of this page with Jinja but it could also be a Bootstrap thing, i am not sure.

As mentioned the jQuery `$(window).scrollTop(value)` is working on other pages within the same web app. 
Also when I add a few breaks `<br>` inside a paragraph `<p></p>` above the Bootstrap grid on the malfunctioning page, the scrollTop function also starts to work here. At least up to where the Bootstrap grind starts.
It seems the bootstrap grid is NOT adding to the window height.
Removing the `load_hide` class doesn't help.
Removing the code for setting the window scroll position on click event and hard coding the scrollTop value doesn't help.
Removing the `container-fluid` on the `main` tag doesn't help.

Not working page

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Sculptures
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<div class="load_hide">
    <div class="row no-gutters scroll_fix ">
        {% for row in entries %}

        <div class="col-sm-4 px-1 scroll_fix ">
            <a href="/carousel?Id_prod={{ row["Path"] }}">
                <div class="img_container scroll_fix ">
                    <img src="static/images/{{ row["Path"] }}/01.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="{{ row["Name"] }}" id="{{ row["Id_prod"] }}">
                </div>
            </a>

            <div class="d-flex flex-column mb-2">
                <div class="p-0 flex_child">{{ row["Name"] }}</div>
                <div class="p-0 flex_child">{{ row["Material"] }}</div>
                <div class="p-0 flex_child">{{ row["Dimensions"] }}</div>
                <div class="p-0 flex_child">&euro;{{ row["Price"] }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>



        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <p>...</p>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Prevent page shaking during page load caused by the scrollTop function
        $('.load_hide').show();
        $(window).scrollTop(localStorage.getItem('scrollPos_scu'));

        // Set window scroll position
        $(document).on('click', 'img', function () {
            var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
            localStorage.setItem("scrollPos_scu", scrollPos);
        });
    });

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Working page

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Inventory
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<h5 class="p-3">Inventory</h5>
<div class="row no-gutters load_hide">
    <div class="table-responsive-sm p-2">

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="w-2 td_pad"></th>
                    <th class="w-2 td_pad"></th>
                    <th class="w-5">No</th>
                    <th class="w-5">Show</th>
                    <th class="w-10">Photo</th>
                    <th class="w-15">Name</th>
                    <th class="w-25">Material</th>
                    <th class="w-10">Dimensions</th>
                    <th class="w-10">Price [&#8364;]</th>
                    <th class="w-5">Year</th>
                    <th class="w-5 p-1" colspan="2"><span class="float-left"><a href="/add_item" class="btn btn-primary btn_create">Create new</a></span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                {% for row in entries %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="td_pad">
                        <a href="/move_up?Id_prod={{ row["Id_prod"] }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_priority">&#8593;</a>
                        <a href="/move_down?Id_prod={{ row["Id_prod"] }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_priority">&#8595;</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="td_pad">
                        <a href="/move_top?Id_prod={{ row["Id_prod"] }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_priority">&#8648;</a>
                        <a href="/move_bot?Id_prod={{ row["Id_prod"] }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_priority">&#8650;</a>
                    </td>

                    <td style="word-break: break-all">{{ row["Priority"] }}</td>

                    {% if row["Show"] == 1 %}
                    <td class="td_checkbox_pad">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input " id="{{ row["Id_prod"] }}" checked>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ row["Id_prod"] }}"></label> <!--A label is required with for="" referencing to the id="" value-->
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    {% else %}
                    <td class="td_checkbox_pad">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{ row["Id_prod"] }}">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ row["Id_prod"] }}"></label> <!--A label is required with for="" referencing to the id="" value-->
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    {% endif %}

                    <td><img src="static/images/{{ row["Path"] }}/00.jpg" class="img-fluid"></td>
                    <td style="word-break: break-all">{{ row["Name"] }}</td>
                    <td style="word-break: break-all">{{ row["Material"] }}</td>
                    <td style="word-break: break-all">{{ row["Dimensions"] }}</td>
                    <td style="word-break: break-all">{{ row["Price"] }}</td>
                    <td style="word-break: break-all">{{ row["Year"] }}</td>

                    <td class="td_pad"> <a href="/edit_item?Id_prod={{ row["Id_prod"] }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn_edit_delete ">Edit</a></td>
                    <td class="td_pad"> <a href="/delete?Id_prod={{ row["Id_prod"] }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn_edit_delete confirm">Detele</a></td>
                </tr>

                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Prevent page shaking during page load caused by the scrollTop function
        $('.load_hide').show();
        $(window).scrollTop(localStorage.getItem('scrollPos_inv'));

        // Set window scroll position
        $("a").click(function () {
            var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
            localStorage.setItem("scrollPos_inv", scrollPos);
        });
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Layout page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!--MOD-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="/static/favicon.ico" rel="icon">

    <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <title><!-- ..... -->: {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

</head>

<body>
    <nav>
       <!-- ............ -->
    </nav>


    {% if get_flashed_messages() %}
    <header>
        <div class="alert alert-primary border text-center" role="alert">
            {{ get_flashed_messages() | join(" ") }}
        </div>
    </header>
    {% endif %}


    <main class="container-fluid py-1 px-0">
        <!--MOD  container-fluid -->
        {% block main %}{% endblock %}
    </main>


    <footer class="page_footer ">
        <!-- ........ -->
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

I don't understand what is causing the difference in behavior between the two pages. 
Can someone tell me what the problem is?

**EDIT:**
I removed the completely unnecessary Jinja code that was creating a new grid row every 3 images from the not working page (Overflowing of the rows is automatically handled by Bootstrap). Still this didn't solve the problem though.

```html
        <!-- if last column in row -->
        {% if loop.index is divisibleby 3 %}
    </div><div class="row no-gutters scroll_fix ">
        {% endif %}</strong>
```

**EDIT:**
This thread on Stack seems to come close to my problem. According to this thread the problem is related to the *floating* behavior of the Bootstrap grid. Unfortunately I am not able to solve my particular problem.
 
[scrollTop not working with Bootstrap grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070398/scrolltop-not-working-with-bootstrap-grids)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of searching i managed to solve to problem.

The reason why the `$(window).scrollTop(value)` function is working on one page and not on the other is caused by the difference in page content (table versus bootstrap grid filled with images) and the moment the `$(window).scrollTop(value)` is triggered.

For both pages the `$(window).scrollTop(value)` is triggered after the  `$(document).ready(function (){});`. Unfortunately the `$(document).ready(function (){});` only assures that all HTML content is loaded but not NOT images. The not working page is almost completely made of up of images and just a little bit of HTML code. So at the document ready event all the HTML code fits on the screen an the there is no window height to scroll. 

The solution for the not working page is, to trigger the `$(window).scrollTop(value)` function after all the images are loaded. To assure all images are loaded, the `$(document).ready(function (){});`  must be replace with `$(window).on('load', function () {});`, see below solution:

```html
<script>

$(window).on('load', function () {
    // Prevent page shaking during page load caused by the scrollTop function
    $('.load_hide').show();
    $(window).scrollTop(localStorage.getItem('scrollPos_scu'));

    // Set window scroll position
    $(document).on('click', 'img', function () {
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        localStorage.setItem("scrollPos_scu", scrollPos);
    });
});
</script>
```

Please note that this solution is only valid for jQuery 1.8 and up, according following thread:
[why $(window).load() is not working in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650315/why-window-load-is-not-working-in-jquery)

I am using jQuery 3.3.1 and I wasted a lot of time trying to fix the problem with `$(window).load(function () {});`, which is only valid for jQuery versions prior to jQuery 1.8.

Although I am happy to have found a solution I remain concerned about blank loading screens in case the number of images to render increases.